# Android - How to get Google Places data using String address instead of the Place ID?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

Is there a way to get the Google Places data (like longitude, latitude, ratings, name, phone number, etc) using just the given address?

Cause i have a long list, like a really long list of address. And i need to get that address to be pointed on a Google Map and in order for me to do so, i need to get does information first from Google.

Comment: Note that there are caviats to using the Google Places API: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get latitude and longitude by address. Your code.

```
public GeoPoint getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress){

Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> address;
GeoPoint p1 = null;

try {
    address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
    if (address==null) {
       return null;
    }
    Address location=address.get(0);
    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();

p1 = new GeoPoint((double) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                  (double) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

return p1;
}
}
```

You have to add the Places library to your project.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:+.'
```

Comment: Thanks, it can get the coordinates of the location but i still need to get the placeID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Android [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically) or [Geocoding Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) APIs to do this